# Can't figure out how to read xml data in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, xml, foreach, radio-button, reader

I'm not sure how to read out the data from a XML file.

The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Lijsten>
<Lijst>
    <Titel>Discipline</Titel>
    <Waardes>Elektro</Waardes>
    <Waardes>Mechanisch</Waardes>
    <Waardes>Civiel</Waardes>
    <Waardes>Proces</Waardes>
</Lijst>
<Lijst>
    <Titel>Soort</Titel>
    <Waardes>Tekening</Waardes>
    <Waardes>Tekst doc</Waardes>
    <Waardes>Afbeelding</Waardes>
</Lijst>
<Lijst>
    <Titel>Afdruk</Titel>
    <Waardes>Landscape</Waardes>
    <Waardes>Portrait</Waardes>
</Lijst>
<Lijst>
    <Titel>Kleur</Titel>
    <Waardes>Kleur</Waardes>
    <Waardes>Zwart</Waardes>
</Lijst>
<Lijst>
<Titel>Kader</Titel>
<Waardes>Aanwezig</Waardes>
<Waardes>Niet aanwezig</Waardes>
</Lijst>
</Lijsten>
```

I'm trying to create a radio-button menu for every "Lijst".

What I've got so far(not much):

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("iniFile.xml");
while (reader.Read())
{
     while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Lijst"))
     {
          while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Titel"))
          {

          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to read using `XElement`, you can use [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp)

Take a look at this example, to get all titles:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(@"C:\temp\inifile.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//Titel");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
```

or, to get all `Lijst` nodes and then iterate through them to get title and warde values

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(@"C:\temp\inifile.xml");
XmlNodeList nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("//Lijst");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("this is List with title: " + node["Titel"].InnerText);
    Console.WriteLine("it contains wardes: " + node["Titel"].InnerText);
    XmlNodeList wardeNodes = node.SelectNodes("Waardes");
    foreach (XmlNode wNode in wardeNodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("   - " + wNode.InnerText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class and LinqToXML:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(xml);
var buttons = xml.Element("Lijsten")
                 .Elements()
                 .Select(p => new { Titel = p.Element("Titel").Value })
                 .ToArray();
```

Comment: Can this be done without XElement and Linq aswell? Im pretty new to programming and never used any of them before.

Comment: @Niels linq + XElement is safe and simple way. I think, you better can spend some time to learn these two lines, than spend much time to write more code with while-loops and if-condidions